# sort products by description attribute

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 ,In that the product have description attribute and the type is text area. so i can't change 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' to 'yes'. I want to sort products by description attribute. how can i list the products by using description attribute

I want to add the description attribute in "sort by ->drop down list" and will list the products by description attribute when selecting description from the drop down

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('description', 'ASC');
echo "<pre>";print_r($_productCollection->getData());
```

Comment: plz help ,where i put this code? in toolbar.phtml?  there have the code   <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>

Comment: try to add this line : $_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('description', 'ASC'); after $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); in the list.phtml. Ofcourse my advice would be to copy the list.phtml  in your local folder.

Comment: sorry, i want to add the description attribute in "sort by ->drop down list" and listing products by description attribute when selecting description from the drop down

Comment: Please decide what you want exactly and then post.

Comment: the above one is my problem

Answer (score 1):

Check the following article i believe you will find helpful.

[how to sort products in the category products listing](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-sort-products-in-the-category-products-listing.html)